# Find and concatenate all & distinct values in one query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a data set as such

```
id     firstevent   allevents
1       apple       apple, orange
1       apple       apple
1       orange      orange,apple
2       orange      orange,apple
2       orange      orange,apple
3       apple       apple
4       banana      banana,orange, apple
4       orange      orange, apple
4       apple       apple
```

I am using a STRING_AGG to concatenate all values for each Id with the below Query.

```
SELECT  id,
STRING_AGG(FirstEvent,';') as FirstEvent ,
STRING_AGG(FirstEvent,';') as allEvents
from mProcessingTime 
  GROUP BY id
```

My output is like below:

```
id      FirstEvent                allevents
1       apple; apple; orange      apple, orange; apple; orange,apple
2       orange;orange             orange,apple; orange,apple
3       apple                     apple
4       banana; apple; orange     banana,orange, apple; orange, apple; apple
```

I want to modify this output to only the distinct values in the set.
My expected output is:

```
id      FirstEvent                 allevents
1       apple; orange             apple, orange; apple; orange,apple
2       orange                    orange,apple
3       apple                     apple
4       banana; apple; orange     banana,orange, apple; orange, apple; apple
```

I tried using distinct inside the STRING_AGG function, but it isnt working.

Can you help me?

EDIT: added additional information for a clearer picture.

Comment: Be aware that `TOP n` without an `ORDER BY` retrieves *n* **random** rows.

Comment: @stickybit, it was just as a test, but note, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used one column to illustrate the solution but you got the idea:

```
select id,
STRING_AGG(FirstEvent,';') as FirstEvent 
, STRING_AGG(case when rw = 1 then FirstEvent else null end,';') as allevents 
from (
select * , row_number() over (partition by id,firstevent order by id) rw
from xx
) t
group by t.id
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `distinct` and `subquery` as follows:

```
SELECT top 10 id,
STRING_AGG(FirstEvent,';') as FirstEvent 
from (select distinct id  firstevent from mProcessingTime ) t
  GROUP BY id
```

Comment: I just added another field to make myself a little clearer, can you help me with it?